# Spring vault configs are not being applied

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, vault

I am new to Spring vault and somewhat new to Springboot, I am trying to learn this so I need help. Apologies for the very long post though.

Here is my source of the Spring vault project that I have set up looking at various tutorials online

Credential.java

```
package com.example.vault.demoVault;

public class Credential {
    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

CredentialService.java

```
package com.example.vault.demoVault;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate;
import org.springframework.vault.support.VaultResponseSupport;

/**
 * Sample service to demonstrate storing and retrieval of secrets.
 *
 * NOTE: We need to configure Vault and provide the Vault uri in the properties file.
 *
 */
@Service
public class CredentialService {

    @Autowired
    private VaultTemplate vaultTemplate;

    /**
     *  To Secure Credentials
     * @param credentials
     * @return VaultResponse
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     */
    public void secureCredentials(Credential credentials) throws URISyntaxException {

        vaultTemplate.write("secret/gs-vault-config", credentials);
    }

    /**
     * To Retrieve Credentials
     * @return Credentials
     * @throws URISyntaxException
     */
    public Credential accessCredentials() throws URISyntaxException {

        VaultResponseSupport<Credential> response = vaultTemplate.read("secret/gs-vault-config", Credential.class);
        return response.getData();
    }

}
```

DemoVaultApplication.java

```
package com.example.vault.demoVault;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoVaultApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoVaultApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

VaultConfig.java

```
package com.example.vault.demoVault;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.TokenAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.client.VaultEndpoint;
import org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration;

/**
 * Example class to configure Vault beans using AbstractVaultConfiguration
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class VaultConfig extends AbstractVaultConfiguration {

    @Override
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        VaultEndpoint endpoint = new VaultEndpoint();
        endpoint.setScheme("http");
        return new VaultEndpoint();
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {
        return new TokenAuthentication("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
    }
}
```

VaultRestController.java

```
package com.example.vault.demoVault;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@RestController
public class VaultRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CredentialService credentialService;

    @GetMapping("/credential")
    public ResponseEntity<Credential> getCredentialEndpoint() throws URISyntaxException {
        Credential credential = credentialService.accessCredentials();
        return new ResponseEntity<Credential>(credential, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.example.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoVault</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this project I get the error

```
2021-01-25 20:46:26.856 ERROR 66844 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    .
    . //frames omitted due to length constraint
    .
    at com.example.vault.demoVault.DemoVaultApplication.main(DemoVaultApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    .
    . //frames omitted due to length constraint
    .
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    .
    . //frames omitted due to length constraint
    .
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    .
    . //frames omitted due to length constraint
    .
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ClientAuthenticationFactory.createClientAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationFactory.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration.clientAuthentication(VaultBootstrapConfiguration.java:248) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now, from what the understanding that I have developed is that since I am extending my `VaultConfig.java` from `AbstractVaultConfiguration` I do not need the bootstrap.properties file to configure my vault client application and spring would pick up those configs and take care of it by itself but apparently this is not happening and the application does not start because ,apparently, it needs those bootstrap.properties configs. It appears that my application is oblivious of my VaultConfig where I am setting a simple endpoint to work over http and authenticating with my root token. Am I missing something here? I can't figure out looking at the examples on the internet

If the application does need bootstrap.properties like this

```
spring.application.name=gs-vault-config
spring.cloud.vault.token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
```

then what is the point of VaultConfig and AbstractVaultConfiguration?

Furthermore, when I put the bootstrap.properties file in my project the application starts and I have specifically mentioned the property `spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http` but still when I call my end point it gives me the

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection
```

error expecting an https call which I also don't understand why.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance